# Rails API and Rails Front End Sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is a generic question.

I want to build a site for a client who has a medical site with different specialities. He is looking for subdomain based approach so for example liver.domain.com will show content that is keyworded as liver in the db and heart.domain.com will show only heart based content.

The reason he wants it like this is basically driven by business as he has various sponsors who will sponsor their own speciality group (subdomain). The ads that will show in each sub domain will be based on the sponsor who is sponsoring the site.

--

My specific question is this - i was considering building an API based back end and a rails based model-less (controller coffee) based front end for each of the subdomain. This way the sub domains can query the same central db for content that is tagged and the backend will send data that is appropriate only to the front end.

The site also has some purchasing options so i will need to put in HTTPS as well.

Will This set up work. One API based rails side with all the logic and several front end sites with controllers/ Coffee only querying the back end. ???

Let me know if someone has encountered something like this before.

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want model-less rails app. Rails isn't intended to build frontends. Maybe checkout some other tools? AngularJS (frontend) and Grape (API) comes to mind.

Just to clear up some confusion: Both API and controllers are backend and their roles are very similar. Both are used to return some data based on the URL. API will return data in form of JSON or XML etc. and typically Rails controller in form od HTML. This said, you can still use controllers in Rails to return JSON (or any other format) if you want to.

My possible set up for application like this would be:

Rails - for models, scheduled jobs etc.
Grape - mounted inside of Rails app to provide API
Angular - to built frontend

You can even skip rails and write whole backend in Grape. (Or skip Grape and write API in Rails:)).

Comment: Thanks Marek for taking the time to answer. My inclination was to go with angular. Its just more work than rails and i was thinking if it was OK to go with rails as the front end as well to keep technologies on the project contained in rails area.